# Minimize a function with respect to some variables

Tags: matlab, minimize

I have a function

> `function [result] = mleGARCH1(r,a0,a1,b1,mu)`

which I want to minimize with respect to all the variables apart from r which will be an input.

How should I format the `fminsearch` function to obtain that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try an anonymous function:

```
[xmin result] = fminsearch(@(x) mleGARCH1(r,x(1),x(2),x(3),x(4)), [ initial values ]);
```